# Assigning passive values or constants to a user-defined type

Tags: variables, types, fortran, assignment-operator, fortran2003

So I'm working on an automatic differentiation toolbox in Fortran using operator overloading. I have previously implemented this in C++ but really need to get it to work in Fortran.

I have the following module defined in Fortran:

```
     module adopov
         integer        :: indexcount
         integer, parameter :: tape_size = 1000
!
!....... ADtype
         public         :: ADtype
         type ADtype
            integer     :: index      = -1
            real        :: v          = 0.0
!
         contains
            procedure        :: oo_asg
            generic, public  :: assignment(=) => oo_asg
         end type ADtype
!
!....... class tape
         public         :: ADtape
         type ADtape
            real        :: v          = 0.0
         end type ADtape
!
!....... interface(s)
         interface assignment(=)
            module procedure oo_asg
         end interface
!
         type (ADtape), dimension(tape_size)  :: tape
!
!....... definitions
         contains
!
!....... assignment
         subroutine oo_asg (x,y)
            implicit none
            class(ADtype), intent(out)  :: x
            class(ADtype), intent(in)   :: y
!
            tape(indexcount)%v          = y%v
            indexcount = indexcount + 1
            x%v     = y%v
            x%index = indexcount
         end subroutine oo_asg
!
end module adopov
```

In C++, I have a similar user-defined type as

```
class ADType {
    public:
      int index;
      double v;
      ADType() : index(-1), v(0) {};
      ADType(const double&);
      ADType& operator=(const ADType&);
  };
```

where the constructor sets the initial values for the index and value parts. Next, I have a constructor for passive values or constants (of type double) so that I can define a new variable of class (`ADType`) whenever I have a double variable. For example, when I have:

```
ADType x;
x = 2.0;
```

initially a new variable of type `ADType` is created with value set to 2.0, let's say `var1 = 2.0` and next (according to the assignment operator (=) defined in the class `ADType`) I will assign that variable to x, i.e. `x = var1`. This entire process is being recorded in a tape that counts operations and records the values and indices.

Now, you may say "why do you have to do this?". Well, during the adjoint method of automatic differentiation using operator overloading, this is a necessary step.

The way I do it in C++ is that I simply have the following two constructors:

```
ADType:: ADType(const double& x): v(x) {
  tape[indexcounter].v = x;
  indexcounter++;
};

ADType& ADType::operator=(const ADType& x) {
  if (this==&x) return *this;
  tape[indexcounter].v = v = x.v;
  indexcounter++;
  return *this;
}
```

but I don't know how to implement the constructor for passive values and constants in Fortran.

Comment: It's your program, but if you use small letters in C++ why not use them in Fortran as well? They are more readable. And you don't need `= 0.D0`, `= 0` is perfectly fine, even if your variables were doubles. And because your variables are default reals then there is no need of the D at all.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the tips. I guess it's just an old habit

Comment: @VladimirF just edited the question to make it more readable

Comment: That's fine, it is your code, you decide.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, that you might use in combination.

1. Overload the defined assignment with a procedure that corresponds to having a REAL object on the right hand side.

   ```
   TYPE ADTYPE
     ...
   CONTAINS
     PROCEDURE        :: OO_ASG
     PROCEDURE        :: ASSIGN_FROM_REAL
     GENERIC, PUBLIC  :: ASSIGNMENT(=) => OO_ASG, ASSIGN_FROM_REAL
   END TYPE AREAL

   ! Users of the module shoudn't be calling this procedure 
   ! (or the specific binding, really) directly.
   PRIVATE :: ASSIGN_FROM_REAL

   ...

   SUBROUTINE ASSIGN_FROM_REAL(x,y)
     CLASS(ADTYPE), INTENT(OUT)  :: x
     REAL, INTENT(IN)   :: y

     ! Do what you have to do...
     ...
     x%V = y
   END SUBROUTINE ASSIGN_FROM_REAL

   ! Example of use...
   TYPE(ADTYPE) :: z
   z = 2.0
   ```
2. Use a structure constructor, or the overloaded procedural equivalent.

   ```
   INTERFACE ADTYPE
     MODULE PROCEDURE ADTYPE_construct_from_REAL
   END INTERFACE ADTYPE
   PRIVATE :: ADTYPE_construct_from_REAL
   ...

   FUNCTION ADTYPE_construct_from_REAL(y) RESULT(x)
     REAL, INTENT(IN) :: y
     TYPE(ADTYPE) :: x

     ! Do what you have to do.
     ...
     x%V = y
   END FUNCTION ADTYPE_construct_from_REAL

   ! Example of use:
   TYPE(ADTYPE) :: z
   z = ADTYPE(3.0)
   ```

If you made the invocation of the constructor that takes a double explicit in the source code in your C++ example (i.e `ADType x; x = ADType(2.0);`, then you have the equivalent to the second of these two approaches - Fortran does not have implicit conversions between objects of derived type.

(Your example code shows both a type bound assignment and a Fortran 90 style stand-alone interface.  It does not make sense to have both - that module should not even compile.)

Comment: @lanH Thank you for your answer and suggestions. I am now using the first approach to avoid having the **explicit** conversion. Another reason for wanting to have implicit conversion was to avoid overloading all the binary operations with special procedures that would handle real vs. derived type (and also derived type vs. real) scenarios. It required more coding but I got it implemented into the module. In C++ I could convert the 'double' values to derived type in-place and then perform overloaded operations. Any suggestions as to how to do this more efficiently in Fortran? Thanks

Comment: Fortran doesn't have implicit conversions between objects of derived type.  This has its benefits - it makes overload resolution very straight forward.  Just use an explicit procedure reference or structure constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working suggestion to your problem. Please note that every variable inside a module automatically inherits the `save` attribute. If you're eventually interested in concurrency you may have to enclose `indexcounter` inside `ADtape` with an appropriate type-bound procedure for bookkeeping.

```
module adopov

  use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_binding, only: &
       ip => C_INT, &
       wp => C_DOUBLE

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  ! Everything is private unless stated otherwise
  private
  public :: Adtype, wp

  ! Declare derived data types
  type ADtape
     real(wp) :: v = 0.0_wp
  end type ADtape

  type, public :: ADtype
     integer(ip) :: index = -1
     real(wp)    :: v = 0.0_wp
   contains
     procedure, private :: asgn_from_type, asgn_from_real, asgn_from_int
     generic, public  :: assignment(=) => asgn_from_type, asgn_from_real, asgn_from_int
  end type ADtype

  ! Set user-defined constructor
  interface ADtype
     module procedure :: ADtype_constructor
  end interface ADtype

  ! Variables confined to the module.
  ! Please note that every variable
  ! in a module implicitly inherits the save attribute.
  integer            :: indexcount = 0 ! Your original code left this uninitialized
  integer, parameter :: TAPE_SIZE = 1000
  type (ADtape)      :: tape(TAPE_SIZE)

contains

  pure function ADtype_constructor(x, indx) result (return_value)
    real (wp),    intent(in)            :: x
    integer (ip), intent (in), optional :: indx
    type (ADtype)                       :: return_value

    return_value%v = x
    if (present(indx)) return_value%index = indx

  end function ADtype_constructor

  subroutine update_tape(float)
    real (wp), intent (in) :: float

    tape(indexcount)%v = float
    indexcount = indexcount + 1

  end subroutine update_tape

  subroutine asgn_from_type(this, y_type)
    class(ADtype), intent(out) :: this
    class(ADtype), intent(in)  :: y_type

    associate( &
         v => this%v, &
         indx => this%index &
         )

      call update_tape(y_type%v)
      v = y_type%v
      indx = indexcount
    end associate

  end subroutine asgn_from_type

  subroutine asgn_from_real(this, y_real)
    class(ADtype), intent(out) :: this
    real(wp),      intent(in)  :: y_real

    associate( &
         v => this%v, &
         indx => this%index &
         )
      call update_tape(y_real)
      v = y_real
      indx = indexcount
    end associate

  end subroutine asgn_from_real

  subroutine asgn_from_int(this, y_int)
    class(ADtype), intent(out) :: this
    integer(ip),   intent(in)  :: y_int

    associate( &
         v => this%v, &
         indx => this%index, &
         float => real(y_int, kind=wp) &
         )
      call update_tape(float)
      v = float
      indx = indexcount
    end associate

  end subroutine asgn_from_int

end module adopov

program main

  use, intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: &
       stdout => OUTPUT_UNIT, &
       compiler_version, &
       compiler_options

  use adopov, only: &
       ADtype, wp

  ! Explicit typing only
  implicit none

  type(ADtype) :: foo, bar, woo

  ! Invoke the user-defined constructor
  foo = ADtype(42.0_wp)
  bar = ADtype(42.0_wp, -6)
  woo = foo

  print *, foo
  print *, bar
  print *, woo

  write( stdout, '(/4a/)') &
       ' This file was compiled using ', compiler_version(), &
       ' using the options ', compiler_options()

end program main
```

This yields

```
gfortran -Wall -o main.exe adopov.f90 main.f90
./main.exe
           1   42.000000000000000     
           2   42.000000000000000     
           3   42.000000000000000     

 This file was compiled using GCC version 6.1.1 20160802 using the options -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -Wall
```