# Fortran derived types

Tags: interface, fortran, derived-types

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to define a derived type in Fortran which automatically returns the right type, without calling the type specifically e.g. `var%real`? Here's an example to explain what I mean:

```
module DervType

  implicit none

  type, public :: mytype
    real(8) :: r
    integer :: i
    logical :: l
  end type

end module DervType

program TestType

  use DervType

  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: test

  test = 1.                   !! <-- I don't want to use test%r here

end program TestType
```

Would this be possible by defining some sort of interface assignment (overload the =) or something like that? Is this even possible?

Thanks! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have defined assignment.  Can you try that to see whether it does what you want?  I guess this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50839842/3157076), but you can do this without the polymorphism.

Comment: See also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39951258/3157076).

Comment: But this is a very specific aspect of your question.  That is, `test = x` can be done so that the component of `test` set is in some way determined by the type of `x`.  However, is this what you mean?  The part "which automatically returns the right type" suggests you may need to do something more exotic (like `call sub(test)` acts like `call sub(test%r)` if the argument is real, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I guess this is all related even though I gave up on the other stuff... If I compile the above I get: `Error: Can't convert REAL(4) to TYPE(mytype)`, so this does not work. Sorry, I've looked at the example from your link but I don't understand it. I do need an interface right?

Comment: Yes, the message `Error: Can't convert REAL(4) to TYPE(mytype)` is about _intrinsic assignment_.  You'll need to set up defined assignment, as covered in other questions.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28174711/3157076) may help.

Comment: So I'll have to define a couple of functions (real, int, logic) and assign them through the interface? Gonna try that! Thanks!

Comment: Do you also want `x = test` to work, where x is a real and the actual operation would be `x = test%r`? I don't think that it is possible but it comes to mind when reading your question.

Comment: Hey Pierre! Yes, that’s exactly what I want. Guess it could be done by overriding the “=“ but I’m still playing around with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution to this and it was actually quite simple. Here's the code:

```
module DervType

  implicit none

  type, public :: mytype
    real(8)                       :: r
    integer                       :: i
    character(len=:), allocatable :: c
    logical :: l
  end type

  interface assignment(=)                 // overload = 
    module procedure equal_func_class
  end interface

contains

  subroutine equal_func_class(a,b)

    implicit none

    type(mytype), intent(out) :: a
    class(*), intent(in)      :: b

    select type (b)
        type is (real)
            print *, "is real"
            a%r = b
        type is (integer)
            print *, "is int"
            a%i = b
        type is (character(len=*))
            print *, "is char"
            a%c = b
        type is (logical)
            print *, "is logical"
            a%l = b 
    end select

    return

  end subroutine equal_func_class  

end module DervType

program TestType

  use DervType

  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: test

  test = 1.      // assign real 
  test = 1       // assign integer
  test = "Hey"   // assign character
  test = .true.  // assign logical

  print *, "Value (real)      : ", test%r
  print *, "Value (integer)   : ", test%i
  print *, "Value (character) : ", test%c
  print *, "Value (logical)   : ", test%l

end program TestType
```

I'm trying to use the variables within a program now (e.g. do some arithmetic calculations, etc.) but that seems to be rather difficult if not impossible. I might start another question about that.

Comment: This is a bad idea. When someone references `test` you have no way of knowing which value they want - the real, integer, logical or character. So your assignment looks different from your value access, which is confusing.

Comment: Well, I guess this depends on how you would like to use it. At the moment I agree that this is the case but that was not part of this question. I simply wanted to find out how or if it is possible to assign a value to a deferred type without knowing the input type. At the moment I'm working on the other way round.

Comment: Actually, the solution with many procedures inside an interface has the advantage that if you try to assign a type that is not covered, you get a compile-time error. Otoh, using a class(*) with a select type, the best you could have is a run-time error (consider using a select default clause)