# "Operation is invalid" when overloading addition for a derived type using ifort

Tags: fortran, operator-overloading, intel-fortran

This is a follow up question from a thread I've started earlier [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515616/fortran-derived-types)

Basically, what I want to achieve is defining a deferred type which automatically assigns primitive types *(real, integer, character and logical).* You can see a working example when following the above link and it compiles with `gcc version 7.3.0` and `ifort version 18.0.0`.

I have now extended the code in order to "use" the deferred data type without knowing what primitive type is assigned. This works by overriding basic operators. For the sake of simplicity I've only included the `+` operator in the following example. The example works and compiles with **gfortran** but does give me an error when compiling with **ifort** :

> error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.   [PLUS_FUNC_CLASS]
>   c%i = a%i + b%i

Does anyone know what the problem is here? I've already googled the error but I could not find out what I'm doing wrong.

---

#### NOTE

in order to match the precision I used the following **compile flags**

`ifort -r8 -i8 tst.f90`

`gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-integer-8 -fdefault-double-8 tst.f90`

---

Here's the sample code:

```
module DervType

  implicit none

  type, public :: mytype
    real                          :: r
    integer                       :: i
    character(len=:), allocatable :: c
    logical                       :: l
  end type

  interface assignment(=)
    module procedure equal_func_class
  end interface

  interface operator(+)
    module procedure plus_func_class
  end interface

contains

   subroutine equal_func_class(a,b)
        type(mytype), intent(out):: a
        class(*),     intent(in) :: b

        select type (b)
            type is (mytype)
                print *, "is mytype"
                if ( .not. a%r == b%r ) a%r = b%r      !! <-- ugly, but necessary not to end up in an endless loop when reassigning mytype (only testing and assigning real here)
            type is (real)
                print *, "is real"
                a%r = b
            type is (integer)
                print *, "is int"
                a%i = b
            type is (character(len=*))
                print *, "is char"
                a%c = b
            type is (logical)
                print *, "is logical"
                a%l = b 
        end select

    return

  end subroutine equal_func_class


  recursive function plus_func_class(a,b) result(c)
        class(*), intent(in)        :: a
        class(*), intent(in)        :: b
        type(mytype)                :: c

        select type (a)
            type is (mytype)
                print *, "left side is mytype"

                !! -------------------------------
                !! only testing one case here and only real operations are
                !! taken care of!
                !! -------------------------------
                select type (b)
                    type is (mytype)
                        print *, "right side is mytype"                       
                        c%i = a%i + b%i  !! <-- this is where ifort throws the error
                        c%r = a%r + b%r  !! <-- this is where ifort throws the error 
                    type is (real)
                        print *, "right side is real", a%r
                        c = a%r + b
                end select

            !! do similar logic when the operands changing sides
            type is (real)
                print *, "left side is real"
        end select

        !c = 1.

        return        

    end function plus_func_class


end module DervType

program TestType

  use DervType

  implicit none

  type(mytype) :: test, test2, res, res2

  real, parameter :: tt = 2.

  test = 1.
  test = 1
  test = "Hey Tapir"
  test = .true.

  test2 = 2.

  test = test2

  print *, "test = ", test%r

  res  = test + 1.0
  res2 = test + tt

  print *, "Calculation 1 (real) : ", res%r
  print *, "Calculation 2 (real) : ", res2%r

end program TestType
```

When compiling with `gfortran` and running the program this gives the following output:

```
 is real
 is int
 is char
 is logical
 is real
 is mytype
 test =    2.0000000000000000     
 left side is mytype
 right side is real   2.0000000000000000     
 is real
 is mytype
 left side is mytype
 right side is real   2.0000000000000000     
 is real
 is mytype
 Calculation 1 (real) :    3.0000000000000000     
 Calculation 2 (real) :    4.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Please do not use such unspecific titles, make the title describe your actual problem, for example the error message or the code you are trying to implement.

Comment: Loks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's cut this example program down to something more manageable:

```
 module DervType

  implicit none

  type mytype
    integer i
  end type mytype

  interface operator(+)
    module procedure plus_func_class
  end interface

contains

  recursive function plus_func_class(a,b) result(c)
    class(*), intent(in)        :: a
    class(*), intent(in)        :: b
    type(mytype)                :: c

    c%i = 1+1
  end function plus_func_class

end module DervType
```

ifort 18.0.3 for me complains about this:

```
error #6303: The assignment operation or the binary expression operation is invalid for the data types of the two operands.   [PLUS_FUNC_CLASS]
    c%i = 1+1
-----------^
```

Familiar?

Well, it looks like because we have the arguments to `plus_func_class` as unlimited polymorphic ifort is deciding to take this function as a specific procedure for the generic `operator(+)` with the expression `1+1`.  (Remove the `recursive` prefix to see further.)

We don't want it to do that.  Can we persuade it not to?

We want our true function to consider cases where either the left-hand side or the right-hand side are of `class(mytype)`, as we don't care to reimplement `intrinsic+intrinsic`.  I won't write out details, but you can implement the function twice: once with LHS `class(mytype)` and RHS `class(*)`, and once with the LHS `class(*)` and the RHS `class(mytype)`.

---

Even if one initially views this approach simply as a "compiler bug workaround", it's really worth implementing the defined operation without using unlimited polymorphic arguments for both sides of the addition operation

When you want to create a new type `mytype2` you don't want to define the operation with the function `plus_func_class`.  You'd need to though, because you'll have an ambiguous interface if you create a new specific function for generic `operator(+)`.

Comment: I see, I had only a short glimpse. Shouldn't gfortran also call the overloaded function recursively for the sum of two integers?

Comment: I tried to avoid thinking about what the correct behaviour actually is, as I have an intuition of what should happen but I can't immediately _prove_ it.  Intuitively, because `1+1` as an intrinsic operation has a higher precedence than that with the defined operation accepting unlimited polymorphic, that is the correct operation.   Where it gets tricky is that even with intrinsic addition the `operator(+)` is still generic, so it could be that it is actually illegal to use the `equal_func_class` of the question...

Comment: Thanks for the answer even though I don't really understand what to do now. I have tested your advice of implementing the function twice and switch the argument types. Now I get the error: `error #6645: The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit.`
Seems like it won't allow me to implement the function twice?

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig, you'll need to use different names for each implementation, both then under the `interface operator(+)`.  If you're doing that and there's still a problem, then perhaps a new question would be the clearest way for us to see.

Comment: Thanks! That actually works! This approach implements quite a bit of code redundancy but I guess this can be solved by defining some additional private functions. Final question: would you consider this as a bug? Should I create a bug report at Intel?

Comment: @FlorianRagossnig, currently, I can't decide whether it's a bug (see my above comment in reply to Vladimir F).  It could be that your code is invalid Fortran.  Either way, though, I'd say it's worth reporting to Intel: "fix the bug" or "improve the diagnostics" could be Intel's decision to make.  (You could, of course, wait for someone who does know the answer to reply.)